# Unable to edit or delete file

Tags: 2007

We have an excel file that shows as being checked out by a user. However as an admin I do not have the option to force check-in and I also cannot delete the file. I did duplicate the file and the duplicate is usable without any issue.

There is no sign this file is checked out until after you attempt to check it out it loads the file after popping up the normal window asking if you want to check it out. Only after it is loaded after you check it out it tells you it was already checked out.

I have tried deleting the file in windows explorer view and it deletes the file but if I reload the window the file is back. I also tried the normal way but it gives me an error saying a user has it checked out.

The user who has the file checked out also looked and he does not show as having it checked out on his screen.

Comment: is it possibly hiding in his sharepoint drafts folder on his computer he can launch and try to check in?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the short-term lock. I suggest you to read [this post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/how-to-use-powershell-to-delete-short-term-locks-from-documents-opened-from-sharepoint/), and then try the suggested PowerShell script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSharePointSiteUrl
$list = $web.Lists["YourDocLib"] 
$item = $list.GetItemById(2) 
$file = $item.File
$userId = $file.LockedByUser.ID
$user = $web.AllUsers.GetByID($userId) 
$impSite= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $user.UserToken); 
$impWeb = $impSite.OpenWeb(); 
$impList = $impWeb.Lists[$list.Title] 
$impItem = $impList.GetItemById($item.ID) 
$impFile = $impItem.File
$impFile.ReleaseLock($impFile.LockId)
```